# Ant tasks don't run IN IzPack installer

Tags: ant, izpack

.
Hello, everyone

I'm studying IzPack as a tool to be used in a future project and I'm really enjoying it. It's as flexible as I need and makes the process much more easy. I have even submmited a silly [pull reques](https://github.com/izpack/izpack/pull/261)t at github with a modification I needed to my purposes. Who knows?

Although I don't find it particularly complicated, I've been stuck trying to use a resource for some days. I need that certain Ant Tasks to be executed in certain points of the installation process (right before everything is unpacked is the really one that matters) and that is not working, besides all the efford. :(

My current state, that seems right looking at examples, is the following:

**[** My current use of this is based on an example I found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.izpack/izpack-event/5.0.0-beta11/com/izforge/izpack/event/ant/AntActionsSpec.xml?av=f) (the docs don't clear too much when It cames to these kind of Actions.**]**

In my definitions xml file, I included some things:

First, the AntActionsSpect.xml and the .jars, followed by the listeners:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <res id="AntActionsSpec.xml" src="specs/AntActionsSpec.xml" />
    ...
</resources>

<jar src="libs/ant/ant.jar" stage="both" />
<jar src="libs/ant/ant-launcher.jar" stage="both" />

<listeners>
    <listener classname="AntActionInstallerListener" stage="install" />
    <listener classname="AntActionUninstallerListener" stage="uninstall" />
</listeners>

<pack name="test_app" required="yes" installGroups="Application Core">
...
```

In the specs/AntActionsSpec.xml file, I have the following:

```
<pack name="test_app">
    <antcall order="beforepacks" quiet="no" verbose="yes" buildfile="$INSTALL_PATH/ant-tasks.xml">
            <property name="INSTALL_PATH" value="$INSTALL_PATH" />
            <target name="touch_beforepacks" />
    </antcall>
 </pack>
```

And the ant-tasks.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <target name="touch_beforepacks">
        <touch file="$INSTALL_PATH/beforepacks.txt"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Nothing special here, just creating a dumb file.

The ant-tasks.xml is unpacked right before anyone else. Everything builds with no error, even if I create one "mistake" at AntActionsSpec or ant-tasks.xml, what suggests me that they aren't even been loaded, though if I mess with the path where the definitions file has them, the build will fail.

I would like some help addressing that. I'm probably making some stupid little error and just can't see it by myself. If any of you could provide an example of a running build, that would be sweet.

If I can give any more information, please, let me known so I can update the question.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it using a forum on a Google Groups discussion: [[izpack-user] Quick question on variable substitution.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/izpack-user/0TOAk2AYjrE/QA6hX6IpQl8J)

Unfortunattly the I will conclude that the docs are misleading. The docs in 
["AntActionInstallerListener and AntActionUninstallerListener"](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/AntActionInstallerListener+and+AntActionUninstallerListener) until this date are stating that I should use this listener configuration:

```
<listeners>
    <listener classname="AntActionInstallerListener" stage="install" />
    <listener classname="AntActionUninstallerListener" stage="uninstall" />
</listeners>
```

That is what is up there, in the question. Comparing my XML code with the one in the Google Groups discussion, I found a different use of it:

```
<listeners>
       <listener    installer="AntActionInstallerListener"
                    uninstaller="AntActionUninstallerListener" />
</listeners>
```

In fact, that is the instruction given in the other wiki: [Ant Actions (InstallerListener and UninstallerListener)](http://izpack.org/documentation/custom-actions.html#ant-actions-installerlistener-and-uninstallerlistener), what points out that I something can be wrong under the hood, but that is a story to another episode.

That just works. The Ant tasks are executed properly. :)
I just could not find where freaking Codehaus will allow me to grab a login and edit the docs wiki. >:(  . If someone could endorse-me with some testing and then adjust the wiki for future happiness or just give a link to this tired programmer, I'd be happy.